# Java keyboard input - game development

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener, key-bindings

I have a specific "problem" with a game I'm creating for class.

The game is an implementation of "Break it". To move the platform at the bottom I just used a key listener. The problem is that after the first key press there is a short "lag" or "stutter" before the platform starts moving. How could I prevent this to get a smooth response? Is there another way than KeyListener? KeyBindings?

Here is the key listener implementation

```
private class KeyControl implements KeyListener {

    private int dx = 20;

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            if(dx < 0 )
                dx = -dx;
            gamePanel.movePlatform(dx);
        }

        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            if(dx > 0 )
                dx = -dx;
            gamePanel.movePlatform(dx);
        }

        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            System.out.println("space");
            gamePanel.play();
        }

        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
            gamePanel.pause();
        }

    }
}
```

and here is the method that moves the platform around

```
public void movePlatform(int dx) {
        int nextDX = dx;

        if(paused || init) {
            dx = 0;
        }

        // make sure platform doesnt exceed right border
        if(platform.getX() + platform.getWidth()  + dx> size.getWidth()) {
            if(nextDX < 0)
                dx = nextDX;
            else
                dx = 0;
        }

        // make sure platform doesnt exceed left border
        if(platform.getX() + dx <= 0) {
            if(nextDX > 0)
                dx = nextDX;
            else
                dx = 0;
        }

        platform.setFrame(platform.getX() + dx, platform.getY(), platform.getWidth(), platform.getHeight());
        platformIntervalX = new Interval((int)platform.getX(), (int)(platform.getX() + platform.getWidth()));
        platformIntervalY = new Interval((int)(platform.getY() - platform.getHeight()), (int)platform.getY());
        repaint();
    }
```

Comment: Add code to your question please, we cannot answer your question correctly without it.

Comment: added the code, sorry

Comment: just open a notepad document and write some text, then hold down left arrow and you'll see the short lag that occurs after you press the key and until the cursor starts moving again.

Comment: What does a notepad document have to do with this? And I'd still like an (even more) accurate description of the problem.

Comment: the notepad document simulates the "lag". If you have the cursor at the end of a line in notepad (or even this comment window), and then hold down the left arrow key. You notice a little lag after the first keypress, just before the system detects that you are holding the key down.

Comment: This most likely has to do with your keyboard response times, and with the amount of keys your keyboard can respond to at any given time. I am having a highend gaming keyboard here (with N-key rollover), and am not experiencing any of those issues.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that is directly related to the hardware (keyboard) being used. The problem is only observable if a specific type of keyboard is being used.

Comment: @skiwi: I disagree in that it is a valid question that requires programming technique to solve. The key is not to rely on the hardware-specific key press frequency, to use a Swing Timer to create your own frequency.

Comment: @skiwi it's not a hardware issue, it's a windows setting (there's probably one for linux as well but under linux I never had to mess around with keyboard settings). OP: The delay you are experiencing is actually configurable in the Windows Control Panel under "Keyboard", the setting is called "Repeat delay". You can also configure the frequency with which the key is triggered after the delay. But as Hovercraft said you shouldn't use keypresses for continuous input anyways...

Comment: See edit for new example code.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is not to use the KeyListener's key press for moving your sprite. The key is not to rely on the hardware-specific key press frequency, to use a Swing Timer to create your own frequency. Instead use Key Bindings and a Swing Timer. Start the time on key press and stop it on key release.

For example, run this code and press and release the up-arrow key:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class KeyBindingEg extends JPanel {
   private static final String UP_KEY_PRESSED = "up key pressed";
   private static final String UP_KEY_RELEASED = "up key released";
   private static final int UP_TIMER_DELAY = 50;
   private static final Color FLASH_COLOR = Color.red;

   private Timer upTimer;
   private JLabel label = new JLabel();

   public KeyBindingEg() {
      label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 32));
      label.setOpaque(true);
      add(label);

      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));

      int condition = WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
      InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
      ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
      KeyStroke upKeyPressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false);
      KeyStroke upKeyReleased = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, true);

      inputMap.put(upKeyPressed, UP_KEY_PRESSED);
      inputMap.put(upKeyReleased, UP_KEY_RELEASED);

      actionMap.put(UP_KEY_PRESSED, new UpAction(false));
      actionMap.put(UP_KEY_RELEASED, new UpAction(true));

   }

   private class UpAction extends AbstractAction {
      private boolean onKeyRelease;

      public UpAction(boolean onKeyRelease) {
         this.onKeyRelease = onKeyRelease;
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         if (!onKeyRelease) {
            if (upTimer != null && upTimer.isRunning()) {
               return;
            }
            System.out.println("key pressed");
            label.setText(UP_KEY_PRESSED);

            upTimer = new Timer(UP_TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {

               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  Color c = label.getBackground();
                  if (FLASH_COLOR.equals(c)) {
                     label.setBackground(null);
                     label.setForeground(Color.black);
                  } else {
                     label.setBackground(FLASH_COLOR);
                     label.setForeground(Color.white);
                  }
               }
            });
            upTimer.start();
         } else {
            System.out.println("Key released");
            if (upTimer != null && upTimer.isRunning()) {
               upTimer.stop();
               upTimer = null;
            }
            label.setText("");
         }
      }

   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      KeyBindingEg mainPanel = new KeyBindingEg();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("KeyBindingEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

---

**Edit**

Or a better example, one that moves a sprite in any direction based on a key press of one of the arrow keys. No delay encountered:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class KeyBindingEg2 extends JPanel {
   enum Dir {
      LEFT("Left", KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, -1, 0),
      RIGHT("Right", KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 1, 0),
      UP("Up", KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, -1),
      DOWN("Down", KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, 1);

      private String name;
      private int keyCode;
      private int deltaX;
      private int deltaY;
      private Dir(String name, int keyCode, int deltaX, int deltaY) {
         this.name = name;
         this.keyCode = keyCode;
         this.deltaX = deltaX;
         this.deltaY = deltaY;
      }
      public String getName() {
         return name;
      }
      public int getKeyCode() {
         return keyCode;
      }
      public int getDeltaX() {
         return deltaX;
      }
      public int getDeltaY() {
         return deltaY;
      }      
   }
   public static final int TIMER_DELAY = 10;
   public static final int DELTA_X = 2;
   public static final int DELTA_Y = DELTA_X;
   public static final int SPRITE_WIDTH = 10;
   public static final int SPRITE_HEIGHT = SPRITE_WIDTH;
   private static final String PRESSED = "pressed";
   private static final String RELEASED = "released";
   private static final int PREF_W = 800;
   private static final int PREF_H = 650;
   private Map<Dir, Boolean> dirMap = new EnumMap<>(Dir.class);
   private int spriteX = 0;
   private int spriteY = 0;
   private BufferedImage sprite;
   private Timer animationTimer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new AnimationListener());

   public KeyBindingEg2() {
      for (Dir dir : Dir.values()) {
         dirMap.put(dir, Boolean.FALSE);
      }
      sprite = createSprite();
      setKeyBindings();
      animationTimer.start();
   }

   private BufferedImage createSprite() {
      BufferedImage sprt = new BufferedImage(SPRITE_WIDTH, SPRITE_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics g = sprt.getGraphics();
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, SPRITE_WIDTH, SPRITE_HEIGHT);
      g.dispose();
      return sprt;
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (sprite != null) {
         g.drawImage(sprite, spriteX, spriteY, this);
      }
   }

   private void setKeyBindings() {
      int condition = WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
      InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
      ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

      for (Dir dir : Dir.values()) {
         KeyStroke keyPressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(dir.getKeyCode(), 0, false);
         KeyStroke keyReleased = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(dir.getKeyCode(), 0, true);

         inputMap.put(keyPressed, dir.toString() + PRESSED);
         inputMap.put(keyReleased, dir.toString() + RELEASED);

         actionMap.put(dir.toString() + PRESSED, new DirAction(dir, PRESSED));
         actionMap.put(dir.toString() + RELEASED, new DirAction(dir, RELEASED));
      }

   }

   private class AnimationListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         int newX = spriteX;
         int newY = spriteY;
         for (Dir dir : Dir.values()) {
            if (dirMap.get(dir)) {
               newX += dir.getDeltaX() * DELTA_X;
               newY += dir.getDeltaY() * DELTA_Y;
            }
         }
         if (newX < 0 || newY < 0) {
            return;
         }
         if (newX + SPRITE_WIDTH > getWidth() || newY + SPRITE_HEIGHT > getHeight()) {
            return;
         }
         spriteX = newX;
         spriteY = newY;
         repaint();         
      }
   }

   private class DirAction extends AbstractAction {

      private String pressedOrReleased;
      private Dir dir;

      public DirAction(Dir dir, String pressedOrReleased) {
         this.dir = dir;
         this.pressedOrReleased = pressedOrReleased;
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         if (pressedOrReleased.equals(PRESSED)) {
            dirMap.put(dir, Boolean.TRUE);
         } else if (pressedOrReleased.equals(RELEASED)) {
            dirMap.put(dir, Boolean.FALSE);
         }
      }

   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      KeyBindingEg2 mainPanel = new KeyBindingEg2();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("KeyBindingEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely the think I was looking for. I had heard of KeyBinding but I have never worked with actions before so I was a little puzzled.