# I have to move a char in a Array with a Scanner. (java)

Tags: java

I have got this array gamefield it contains some'R','O','X' and a '+'.  I have to move the X to the +, when the X is at the '+' the game is over. I have to do it with java.util.Scanner but I don´t know how. Can someone help me?

As you can see I have tried it but it does not work. <-- Its everything after //player movement

Code:

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String moveSelect;
    boolean validInput = true;

    int WIDTH = 18;
    int HEIGHT = 11;
    final int CHAR_COUNT = 15;
    final char[] CHARS = {'R','O'};
    Random random = new Random();

//field
    char[][] field = new char[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
        Arrays.fill(field[i], '.');

    }
    for (char ch: CHARS) {

        for (int j = 0,x,y; j < CHAR_COUNT ; j++) {

            do{
                x = random.nextInt(WIDTH);

                y = random.nextInt(HEIGHT);
            } while (field[y][x] != '.');
            field[5][0] = '+';
            field[5][17] = 'X';
            field[y][x] = ch;
        }
    }

    //print field
    for (char[]row : field) {
        System.out.println(row);

    }
// player movements
    System.out.println("Enter a movement choice W A S or D");
    do {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        moveSelect = keyboard.nextLine();

        if (moveSelect.equals("s")) {
           WIDTH -= 1;
        } else if (moveSelect.equals("d")) {
            HEIGHT -= 1;
            validInput = true;
        } else if (moveSelect.equals("w")) {
            WIDTH += 1;
            validInput = true;
        } else if (moveSelect.equals("a")) {
            HEIGHT += 1;
            validInput = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Entry. Try again.");
            validInput = false;
        }

    } while (validInput == false);

    //print field
    for (char[]row : field) {
        System.out.println(row);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: have you considered using the `KeyListener` class? it might work better than `Scanner` in this case. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730715/java-keyboard-input-game-development