# How do I run the key event only once even if the key is hold?

Tags: java

I'm testing this code when I'm making a game with Java 8.

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int keycode = e.getKeyCode();

    switch( keycode ) { 
        case 37:
            System.out.println("left");
            break;
        case 39:
            System.out.println("right");
            break;
        case 38:
            System.out.println("up");
            break;
        case 40:
            System.out.println("down");
            break;
    }
}
```

I found out that when I press an arrow key and hold it, it will print out that key name many times until I release it. If I want it to print the key name only once even if I'm holding the key (and print it again until I release and press it again), what should I do?

I've look at the docs but it says:

> Because of how operating systems handle key repeats, holding down a
> key may cause multiple calls to keyPressed() (and keyReleased() as
> well). The rate of repeat is set by the operating system and how each
> computer is configured. ( end auto-generated )

Comment: @Abra Thanks for the comment, but I'm still confused about how to do that, could you give me an example about how to use `getWhen`?

Comment: In games you're most likely interested in which key is pressed or has been pressed. Keylistner will only give you headaches since it's not designed for real time polling of the keyboard. Instead you should have a class checking the raw awt event queue and keeps track of the keys pressed.  At regular intervals your program check this. Then it becomes easier to handle multiple key presses to.

Comment: I just found this nice question answered by hovercraft:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730715/java-keyboard-input-game-development/22731033#22731033

Answer (score 0):

Call method [getWhen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#getWhen--) to find how much time elapsed between consecutive calls to method `keyReleased`. If the elapsed time is less than a particular amount (say half a second, i.e. 500 milliseconds) then you know that the key is being held down. By the way, with Java 11 on Windows 10 I don't get this behavior. The key name prints only once.

Try the below example app.

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GetsWhen implements KeyListener {

    /** Maximum elapsed time to consider key held down. */
    private static final long THRESHOLD = 500L;

    /** Timestamp of last invocation of method 'keyReleased'. */
    private long lastWhen;

    @Override // java.awt.event.KeyListener
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // Not implemented.
    }

    @Override // java.awt.event.KeyListener
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // Not implemented.
    }

    @Override // java.awt.event.KeyListener
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        long when = e.getWhen();
        long diff = when - lastWhen;
        if (diff > THRESHOLD) {
            int keycode = e.getKeyCode();
            switch (keycode) {
                case 37:
                    System.out.println("left");
                    break;
                case 39:
                    System.out.println("right");
                    break;
                case 38:
                    System.out.println("up");
                    break;
                case 40:
                    System.out.println("down");
                    break;
            }
        }
        lastWhen = when;
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("When");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        textField.addKeyListener(this);
        frame.add(textField);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new GetsWhen().createAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```